# .htaccess RewriteRule with Unlimited Perameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble racking my brain around how to create a RewriteRule in .htaccess to accept unlimited perameters for friendly URLs. Right now, my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteRule "^category/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$" "category.php?cat1=$1" [NC,L]
RewriteRule "^category/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$" "category.php?cat1=$1&cat2=$2" [NC,L]
RewriteRule "^category/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/?$" "category.php?cat1=$1&cat2=$2&cat3=$3" [NC,L]
```

I have this same line repeated about 10 times to accept 10 different categories. Is there an easier way to accomplish this? Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Rules cannot generate parameter names on it's own, it must be part of URL e.g. this is possible `/category/n1/v1/n2/v2 to /category.php?n2=v2&n1=v1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question, here is an alternative to using RewriteRule and .htaccess (Which IMO are more a optimal way to achieve what you want).

Firstly, if at all possible you should favor using your apache server config files over a .htaccess file. There are performance problems as well as potential secuirty problems that arrise from using .htaccess. This is well documented on the internet, so I wont repeat it here, but a quick google search should provide more information.

Secondly, instead of using RewriteRule, a much more scalable solution is to use FallbackResource and a router file.

The idea is if there is ever a request to your site which does not match any of the existing files, the request will be handled by your FallbackResource file.

If in your config (or htaccess) you have

```
FallbackResource router.php
```

and someone makes a request for `example.com/category/potato` the request will cause the server to serve `router.php` (this is assuming category/potato is not actually a file on your server)

So what goes in `router.php`? Well you cannot serve every request the same page of course, so you inspect the details of the request that was made and then serve the correct content accordingly.

a very simple (and untested) router:

```
$request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // eg /category/potato

$path_tokens = explode("/", trim($request_uri, "/"));

if($path_tokens[0] == "category"){
    $category = $path_tokens[1];
    renderCategoryPage($category); // can render the category page for potatoes
}
```

This example is just to give you an idea, you will have to design and implement your own, but hopefully you can see how this gives more freedom that some britle rewrite rules.