# Replace GET parameters in URL from .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

I have this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /%1 [R=307,L]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
```

But whit this method, remove the extension .php but see the get parameters.
For example.:
attractions?id=897236234234

I want this attractions/32456789

Comment: Just to clarify, htaccess is _not_ used to remove the file extension from a URL, it is used to handle URLs where _you_ have removed the file extensions already, and map that to _your_ logic.

Comment: I’m not certain if that code will do what you want, but I’d strongly recommend using one of the two common formats for router scripts, either “URL doesn’t map to a directory or file” or the simple “FallbackResource”: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48816370/231316